# Routing parameter, page not found doesn't cause 404

Tags: php, laravel, routes

```
**-Routes-**
Route::get('/{parameter}', 'myController@show');


**-Controller-**
public function show($parameter)
{
    return view($parameter)->with('parameter', $parameter);
}
```

I tried to using route with parameter, so I can prevent too much create route that is where the link leads to. But the problem is, if route not found, 404.blade.php didn't come up.

> View [a] not found.

Comment: Route found but view `a` is not found, you need to create that view in views folser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check if the view exists, and if it does not, send the 404 response manually:

```
public function show($parameter)
{
    // If the view doesn't exist return a 404 response
    if ( ! view()->exists($parameter)) {
        abort(404);
    }

    return view($parameter)->with('parameter', $parameter);
}
```

If you like, you can also create a custom view to be served for any 404 response. You should place it in `resources/views/errors/404.blade.php` and Laravel will make sure it displays it whenever a 404 HTTP error is triggered. You can read more in the [Laravel Docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/errors#http-exceptions).